# Java - IzPack and EOFException

Tags: java, izpack, eofexception

I have one installer with several packs. None is required. When I mark 
all, the installation completes with success.

When I mark just two packs, I get `EOFException`.

**Edit**

Using trace I can see the stacktrace:

```
Current focus owner: null.glassPane
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.izforge.izpack.installer.Unpacker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Edit 2**

Found JIRA that is closed, but I'm using the 4.3.4 and get the error. Commenting the "pack200" works.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/IZPACK-395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `'-DTRACE=TRUE'` in front of `'-jar'` of the installer call.

Refer to [documentation](http://izpack.org/documentation/advanced-features.html) section "logging install"

Comment: edit2 - `commenting the pack200 works` does that mean you got it solved? consider accepting answer if tracing option that you were looking for as part of original question helped you. This will improve your likeliness of getting further answers on stackoverflow.